# Were there any explanations as for the stability of matter before the advent of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, atomic-physics, history, stability

Reading the paper by Lieb ["The stability of matter"](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123111010/http://www.pas.rochester.edu/%7Erajeev/phy246/lieb.pdf), it is clear from the start that quantum mechanics is absolutely necessary to solve this problem. However, I assume this question was thought of before the birth of Quantum Mechancis. If so, what were the main hypotheses? It seems unsolvable from a classical perspective, and therefore it could be a historically relevant pathway to the formation of Quantum Mechancis. However, I have never seen it mentioned in any historical perspective. So what solves this apparent "paradox"?

Alternative link: [The stability of matter, Elliott H. Lieb (1976)](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.48.553)

Comment: This belongs on [HSM.SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @J.G. the fact of it being on topic for another SE site doesn't necessarily make it off-topic here. (It may or may not be - I'm not to date with current Physics.SE policy. But if it's on topic here it may well get better answers than it would on HSM.)

Comment: [Related meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8930/2451).

Answer (score 7):

According to [Dalton's atomic theory](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095658664) (invented 1803)
atoms were defined to be *indivisible*, i.e. not consisting of any subparticles.
Therefore, at this time, the question why atoms are stable didn't arise.

This theory worked fine until the experimental discoveries that atoms consisted of
sub-particles:

- electrons (1897 [discovered by J.J. Thomson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._J._Thomson#Discovery_of_the_electron))
- a nucleus (1911 [discovered by Rutherford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_nucleus#History))

Answer (score 7):

It wasn't an issue before Geiger, Marsden, and Rutherford discovered that the mass and positive charge of atoms was almost entirely contained in a tiny nucleus. Before that, the assumption was that the volume of condensed matter reflected the volume of whatever stuff its constituent atoms were made of. This seems a reasonable, commonsense assumption, which is why the Rutherford result was such a surprise.

Before the discovery of the nucleus, the [Plum Pudding model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plum_pudding_model) was the most advanced model of atoms, with the "pudding" occupying the volume.